# Scala compile errors: "No implicit view available" and "diverging implicit expansion"

Tags: scala, json4s

```
 def MyFun(result: ListBuffer[(String, DateTime, List[(String, Int)])]):
 String = {
 val json =
  (result.map {
    item => (
      ("subject" -> item._1) ~
        ("time" -> item._2) ~
        ("student" -> item._3.map {
          student_description=> (
            ("name" -> lb_result._1) ~
              ("age" -> lb_result._2) 
            )
        })
      )
    }
    )
    val resultFormat = compact(render(json))
    resultFormat  
}
```

error 1: 
No implicit view available from org.joda.time.DateTime => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.("subject" -> item._1) ~

error 2: diverging implicit expansion for type Nothing => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue starting with method seq2jvalue in trait JsonDSL
     val resultFormat = compact(render(json))

Comment: You need [json4s-ext](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extensions) for joda time support.

Comment: Peter Neyens: can you explain it?

Answer (score 6):

I hinted at *json4s-ext* for *joda-time* support, but only importing this submodule won't solve your problem.

JsonDSL is used to create `JValues` and serializers are only used to turn `JValues` into JSON and vise versa (serialization and deserialization).

If we try to create a simpler json object with a `DateTime` :

```
val jvalue = ("subj" -> "foo") ~ ("time" -> DateTime.now)
```

We get the same error :

```
error: No implicit view available from org.joda.time.DateTime => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.
```

Like I said, the serializers for `DateTime` from *json4s-ext* are not used when we use JsonDSL to create `JValues`.

You could create an implicit function `DateTime => JValue` or do something like `DateTime.now.getMillis` or `DateTime.now.toString` to create respectively a `JInt` or a `JString`, but why would we reinvent the wheel if joda time serializers already exist ?

We can introduce some case classes to hold the data in `result` and then json4s can serialize them for us :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}

implicit val formats = 
  Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) ++ org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers.all

case class Lesson(subject: String, time: org.joda.time.DateTime, students: List[Student])
case class Student(name: String, age: Int)

val result = ListBuffer(("subj", DateTime.now, ("Alice", 20) :: Nil))
val lessons =  result.map { case (subj, time, students) => 
  Lesson(subj, time, students.map(Student.tupled))
}

write(lessons)
// String = [{"subject":"subj","time":"2015-09-09T11:22:59.762Z","students":[{"name":"Alice","age":20}]}]
```

Note that you still need to add *json4s-ext* like Andreas Neumann explained.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Neyens allready said for serializing `org.joda.time.DateTime` you ned the ext package

https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extras

So add this dependency to you `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "3.2.11"
```

Comment: solution found on http://www.itanswerz.com/827911/scala-using-json-andor-xml-templates